# Specifying which version of node to use via git bash

Tags: node.js, git, npm-install, git-bash

I have two different versions of node and I need to choose the second path using git bash.

```
$ where node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
D:\SW's\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\node.exe
```

I tried to set path like the below,

```
PATH=$PATH:/D:\SW's\node-v8.11.2-win-x64/
```

In windows environment setting path(set path="D:\SW's\node-v8.11.2-win-x64/") works fine,where in git bash it is not working,is there any way to use the second path without using nvm and changing env variables ?

Comment: `export PATH=/d/SW's/node-v8.11.2-win-x64:$PATH` didn't work?

Comment: $ export PATH=/d/SW's/Karlo/node-v8.11.2-win-x64:$PATH
> npm start
 Yes I tried Its not working.

Comment: what is it showing??

Comment: after npm start it was asking for next entry from user.

Comment: since you are trying `npm start`, so is there a **package.json** present in that directory?

Comment: yes,I'm trying to run a project